# Existence of an orthogonal transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, orthogonality, orthonormal

Reading a passage from a book I got stuck...

The author says at a certain point:

> "Consider a quadratic form in $k$ complex variables 
>   $$
> Q(z_{1},...,z_{k})=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}z_{h}z_{j}b_{hj}
> $$
>   If we substitute $x^{h}+y^{h}$ for $z^{h}$, and then take the real part of $Q$ we obtain a real quadratic form in $2k$ real variables:
>   $Q'(x_{1},...,x_{k},y_{1},...,y_{k})=$ real part of ($\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}(x_{h}+iy_{h})(x_{j}+iz_{j})b_{hj})$"

Then he wants to prove that

> "If $e$ is an eigenvalue of $Q'$ with multiplicity $\mu$, then $-e$ is also an eigenvalue with the same multiplicity $\mu$"

And to prove that he affirms that the identity
$$
-Q(z_{1},...,z_{k})=Q(iz_{1},...,iz_{k})
$$
shows that the quadratic form $Q'$ can be transformed into $-Q'$ by an orthogonal change of variables and then concludes what we want to prove follows from that.

I understand why the proof is completed if we show that  the quadratic form $Q'$ can be transformed into $-Q'$ by an orthogonal change of variables but it is not clear to me why from the identity above mentioned follows that an orthogonal change of this kind exists.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can write $ Q'(x,y) = Q(x) - Q(y) $ (for $ x,y \in \mathbb{R}^k $). Though, I have a feeling your post contains a handful of typos so I'm not sure whether I understood the question.

Comment: I thinks I edited what was wrong...thanks. I try to understand your answer now, thanks as well.  As regards the question: I don't understand why it follows - from the identity mentioned - that it possibile to transform $Q'$ in $Q$ by an orthogonal change of variables.

Comment: Thanks for the improvements, the orthogonal change of variables you are looking for is \( (x,y) -> (y,x) \): \( Q'(y,x) = Q(y) - Q(x) = -(Q(x)-Q(y)) = -Q'(x,y) \).